# Ошибка сегментирования, но не могу понять, из-за чего

Tags: c++

Имеется класс:

```
class tree{
private:
    vector<node> nodes;
    vector<wstring> codedString;
    int fmax;
    int inode1;
    int inode2;
public:
    void extractString(wstring str); //Разделяем строку на первичные узлы
    void construct();
    void codeString (wstring str);
    void printCodedString();
    void printFreqTable();
    void printCodeTable();
    void codeNodes();
    void code(node& n, int level);
    void selectNode (wstring str);
    wstring decodeString ();
    void findCode (wstring str);
    node findNode (wstring code);
    bool inNodes (wstring str);
    bool inNodes (int freq);
    void getMinNode1();
    void getMinNode2();
};
```

Сам объект `node`:

```
class node{
private:
    int freq, child1, child2;
    wstring sym;
    wstring code;
    bool flag;
public:
    node(int fr, int ch1, int ch2, wstring s, wstring c):freq(fr),child1(ch1),child2(ch2),sym(s),code(c),flag(false){};
    int getFreq();
    int getChild1();
    int getChild2();
    wstring getCode();
    //bool getFlag();
    wstring getSym();
    void incFreq();
    void incCode(int val);
    void toggle();
   //bool operator> (node& n);
   bool operator<= (node& n);
};
```

Функция, создающая вектор с нодами:

```
void tree::extractString (wstring str)
{
    wcout << L"извлекаются узлы из строки" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<str.size()/2; i++){
        wstring tmp = str.substr (i*2, 2);
        if (inNodes(tmp)) selectNode(tmp);
        else {
            node* n = new node (1, -1, -1, tmp, L"");
            nodes.push_back(*n); //тут и возникает ошибка
        }
    }
    wcout << L"узлы извлечены" << endl;
}
```

Так вот, если поле `code` у объекта `node` имеет тип `wstring`, как сейчас - в функции на втором же узле выскакивает ошибка сегментации. Стоит его заменить на int (и заодно поменять реализацию всего, что с этим полем связано) - всё успешно создаётся, но этот тип для моих целей не подходит.

Вопрос: почему вектор из объектов с одним строковым полем создаётся, а с двумя - уже нет? Что здесь не так?

Upd. Тем, кто советует использовать отладчик: вот полученный из g++ бэктрейс.

```
#0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x43e0000041a) at malloc.c:2933
#1  0x0000000000402160 in node::~node() ()
#2  0x000000000040217b in void std::_Destroy<node>(node*) ()
#3  0x0000000000402097 in void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<node*>(node*, node*) ()
#4  0x0000000000401f5a in void std::_Destroy<node*>(node*, node*) ()
#5  0x0000000000401dc3 in void std::_Destroy<node*, node>(node*, node*, std::allocator<node>&) ()
#6  0x0000000000404115 in std::vector<node, std::allocator<node> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<node*, std::vector<node, std::allocator<node> > >, node const&) ()
#7  0x0000000000403b80 in std::vector<node, std::allocator<node> >::push_back(node const&) ()
#8  0x00000000004025b7 in tree::extractString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >) ()
#9  0x0000000000401840 in main ()
```

Из всего этого я понял только одно: что он успешно открыл `main()`, загнал в нужную функцию строку и создал первый узел, а затем вылетел. Что делать дальше, непонятно.

Comment: Тип у nodes какой?

Comment: @Byulent Покажите определение code.

Comment: @Cerbo, `vector<node>`. А вообще-то тут всё вроде как написано.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, в вашей программе имеется утечка памяти. Узлы с именем `n`, создаваемые в этом блоке кода

```
    else {
        node* n = new node (1, -1, -1, tmp, L"");
        nodes.push_back(*n); //тут и возникает ошибка
    }
```

не удаляются.

Нет никакой необходимости создавать эти узлы в динамической области памяти. Вы могли бы написать

```
    else {
        node n(1, -1, -1, tmp, L"");
        nodes.push_back( n );
    }
```

либо

```
    else {
        nodes.emplace_back( 1, -1, -1, tmp, L""); 
    }
```

Что касается ошибки в строке с `push_back`, то она может быть следствием неопределенного поведения вашей программы.

Comment: Исправил, но это мне не помогло.

Comment: @Byulent Как я уже написал, проблема связана с неопределенным поведением вашей программы. Вам надо составить минимально компилируемый пример, который демонстрирует программу. И тогда, возможно, вы даже сами найдете ошибку. Код который вы показали не воспроизводит проблему.